Compare column values between columns having the same suffix but different prefix in the name
Would appreciate some optimization tips here.
I have a pandas dataframe which has about 4500 columns and 50000 rows.
There are 2 kind of columns, ones which start with 'A' and one which start with 'B' .
example columns
[id, A.sellervalue, A.buyervalue, A.ratingvalue, B.sellervalue, B.buyervalue, B.ratingvalue]

I have written this code block which would compare the values for the columns with the same suffix but different prefix (A.sellervalue vs B.sellervalue, A.buyervalue vs  B.buyervalue etc)   and create a new dataframe which would identify the mismatching row by column name and corresponding values.
This is not very efficient.
I was working if there is any optimization I can do here with either Pandas methods or by using pyspark.
Thank You
def find_mismatch_common_columns_values(df, A_cols_without_prefix, B_cols_without_prefix):
    set_A_cols_without_prefix = set(A_cols_without_prefix)
    set_B_cols_without_prefix = set(B_cols_without_prefix)
    common_columns = list(set_A_cols_without_prefix.intersection(set_B_cols_without_prefix))
    
    print("\n Size of common columns between both ",len(common_columns))
        
    result_list = []    
    for col in common_columns:
        A_col = f'A.{col}'
        B_col = f'B.{col}'

        for idx, row in df.iterrows():
            
            A_value = row[A_col]
            B_value = row[B_col]
            
            if isinstance(A_value, float) :
                A_value = round(float(A_value), 6)
            
            if isinstance(B_value, float):
                B_value = round(float(B_value), 6)
                
            
            if A_value != B_value and (not pd.isnull(A_value) and not pd.isnull(B_value)):
                result_list.append({
                    'row': idx,
                    'column_name': col,
                    'A_value': A_value,
                    'B_value': B_value
                })

    
    result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_list)
    return result_df


can you provide an example of what you are trying to accomplish? input/output?

Instead of iterating over all the rows, you can make each column comparison vectorized, which should speed up the processing significantly.
Given this example dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "A.sellervalue": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
        "A.buyervalue": [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0],
        "A.ratingvalue": [100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0, 500.0],
        "B.sellervalue": [1.0, 2.1, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
        "B.buyervalue": [10.0, 21.0, 30.0, 40.0, 51.0],
        "B.ratingvalue": [100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0, 501.0],
    }
)

   id  A.sellervalue  A.buyervalue  A.ratingvalue  B.sellervalue  B.buyervalue  B.ratingvalue
0   1            1.0          10.0          100.0            1.0          10.0          100.0
1   2            2.0          20.0          200.0            2.1          21.0          200.0
2   3            3.0          30.0          300.0            3.0          30.0          300.0
3   4            4.0          40.0          400.0            4.0          40.0          400.0
4   5            5.0          50.0          500.0            5.0          51.0          501.0

Identify the common column names and iterate over them, but make the comparisons using .loc and assign:
common_columns = list(set([col[2:] for col in df.columns if "." in col]))

diff_list = []

for col in common_columns:
    A_col = f"A.{col}"
    B_col = f"B.{col}"

    mask = (df[A_col] != df[B_col]) & df[A_col].notna() & df[B_col].notna()

    diff = df.loc[mask, [A_col, B_col]]
    diff = diff.assign(row=diff.index, column_name=col).rename(
        columns={A_col: "A_value", B_col: "B_value"}
    )

    diff_list.append(diff)

out = pd.concat(diff_list, ignore_index=True)

   A_value  B_value  row  column_name
0      2.0      2.1    1  sellervalue
1     20.0     21.0    1   buyervalue
2     50.0     51.0    4   buyervalue
3    500.0    501.0    4  ratingvalue

